# Linq : compare ListA (Of String) with ListB(of String) and return items in ListA that are not in ListB

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a list of available (open) orders, and a list of Delivered orders,
I want to get the correct list of Available orders by filtering those in the "RemoveThis" list of strings

```
  Dim Available As New List(Of String)
  Available.Add("1")
  Available.Add("2")
  Available.Add("3")
  Available.Add("4")

  Dim RemoveThis As New List(Of String)
  RemoveThis.Add("2")
  RemoveThis.Add("3")
```

Does not work

```
  Dim x = From a In Available
          From b In RemoveThis
          Select a.Except(b)
```

Comment: Surely you just want `Dim x = Available.Except(RemoveThis)` don't you? It's not clear why you're using a query expression at all.

Comment: `ListA.Except(ListB).ToList()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing the Linq query in the way you have is resulting in too many results being returned due to the way the two collections are joined.  You can simply do:

```
Dim x = Available.Except(RemoveThis)
```

To get the list you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Strange... I was playing with the List initializers and came up with this:

```
    Dim Available As New List(Of String)(New String() {"1", "2", "3", "4"})
    Available.Add("1")
    Available.Add("2")
    Available.Add("3")
    Available.Add("4")

    Dim RemoveThis As New List(Of String)(New String() {"2", "3"})
    Dim l As List(Of String) = Available.Except(RemoveThis).ToList
    MsgBox(String.Join(", ", l))
```

I forgot to remove the .Add lines so I wound up with a list of 8 elements, two series of 1,2,3,4. Strange part is list `l` only has two elements. I expected four.

Not an answer, just an observation.

Comment: The reason for this can be seen in [the referencesource](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/system/linq/Enumerable.cs,785) - it tries to add each item to a collection and only if successfully added is it returned, so the duplicates are left out as they don't get added as they're already in the set, but yes - the [documentation for `Except`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb300779(v=vs.100).aspx) doesn't really make this clear.

Comment: `Available` winds up with 8 elements in the code above so the duplicates are present in the List. I guess `it` is a collection inside of `Except`. The `Except` doc should mention it is returning unique/distinct items if that is the case.